# Connect4 game in java eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

How can I check for a draw? I have managed to check for Both diagonals left and right and both horizontal and vertical. But I need an idea how to check for a draw. I know I need to check all buttons (buttons[6][7] in my case).

```
//Checking the Diagonal_right win

for (int i  = 0; i < 6 ; i ++){
    for (int j  = 0; j < 7; j ++){
        if ((i+1)==6 || (i+2)==6 || (i+3)==6){
            break;
        }

        if(imageName[i][j] == singleimageName && 
                imageName[i+1][j-1] == singleimageName &&
                imageName[i+2][j-2] == singleimageName &&
                imageName[i+3][j-3] == singleimageName){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,""
                    + "You Have Won! \n"
                    + "Player Using " + singleimageName +
                    " Connected 4");
            clearGrid();

        }
    }
}

//Checking the Horizontal win

for (int i  = 0; i < 6; i ++){
    for (int j  = 0; j < 7; j ++){
        if ((i+1)==6 || (i+2)==6 || (i+3)==6){
            break;
        }

        if(imageName[i][j] == singleimageName && 
                imageName[i][j+1] == singleimageName &&
                imageName[i][j+2] == singleimageName &&
                imageName[i][j+3] == singleimageName) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,""
                    + "You Have Won! \n"
                    + "Player Using " + singleimageName +
                    "  Connected 4");
            clearGrid();

        }
    }
}

//Checking the Vertical win

for (int i  = 0; i < 6; i ++){
    for (int j  = 0; j < 7; j ++){
        if ((i+1)==6 || (i+2)==6 || (i+3)==6){
            break;
        }

        if(imageName[i][j] == singleimageName && 
                imageName[i+1][j] == singleimageName &&
                imageName[i+2][j] == singleimageName &&
                imageName[i+3][j] == singleimageName) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,""
                    + "You Have Won! \n"
                    + "Player Using " + singleimageName +
                    "  Connected 4");
            clearGrid();

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If the array is full and no one has one then it's a draw right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
// Check for a draw
boolean draw = true;
for (int i  = 0; i < 6; i ++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < 7; j ++) {
        if (imageName[i][j].getIcon() == null) {
            draw = false;
        }

if (draw) {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "It's a draw!");
    clearGrid();
}
```

Comment: initially i set the button value to icon (png) of a picture... so i was wondering if there was a condition that can check if the all the buttons were filled?

Comment: Sure. You just need to iterate through all `JButtons` in your array and individually check for each `JButton` if it has an Icon attached. I've updated my answer.